# Orchard project workflow 1.7.2: Send Email node missing

Tags: orchardcms, sendmail, orchardcms-1.7

in my Orchard project I am trying to send email after form is submitted, but there is no Send Email node in workflows.

I added Messaging module and Email Messaging module, I set sender email...but still no Sende Email node.

Any ideas (orchard 1.7.2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your settings and the modules you have enabled. It should be there.
It shows in mine even if the SMTP details are not set.

Comment: Checked but still the same...@ErMasca what version do you have?

Comment: Im in 1.7.2 too. Weird... Whats your environment like? Have you checked the logs? Have you tried to install orchard again?

Comment: A was using WebMatrics...today I will start again using Visual Studio (whole source code). We will see. Thanks for now.